# stuck with jquery function for css element displayer and hider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a function in jquery which displays the hidden css elements on window resize and now I'm stuck with, if window re-size to default then hide the elements....I'm not getting how to do that...

```
var cwidth = $(window).width();
$(window).on('resize', function(event){
    profdisplayer();
});

function profdisplayer()
{
    var i=1390;
    var j=1;
    for(; j<=5;j++){          
        if (cwidth>i){    
            $("#d"+j).show();
            i=i+600;
        }
    }
}
```

html

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="containerchild">
<div id="hidden"></div>
        <div id="myfavcontainer">
            <div id="myfav"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="profilecontainer">
                <div id="abouttab"></div>
                <div id="horirule620"></div>
                <div id="profiledata"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="d1"></div>
        <div id="d2"></div>
        <div id="d3"></div>
        <div id="d4"></div>
        <div id="d5"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

css

```
#container{
height:100%;
width:100%;
background-color:#000;

}
#containerchild{
height:100%;
width:100%;
float:right;
margin:0 0 0 0;
position:relative;
}
#hidden{
height:100%;
width:174px;
float:right;
}
#myfavcontainer{
height:100%;
width:575px;
float:left;
position:absolute;
margin:0 0 0 0;
background-color:#31353E;
}
#profilecontainer{
height:100%;
width:600px;
float:left;
position:absolute;
margin: 0 0 0 575px;
background-color:#31353E;
box-shadow:inset 7px 0 7px -7px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 7px 0 7px -7px #000;
-moz-box-shadow:inset 7px 0 7px -7px #000;
-ms-box-shadow:inset 7px 0 7px -7px #000;
-o-box-shadow:inset 7px 0 7px -7px #000;
}
#horirule620{
height:1px;
width:600px;
float:left;
background-color:#1C1D22;
}
#myfav{
height:620px;
width:575px;
background-color:#fff;
position:relative;
margin:0 0 0 0;
}
#abouttab{
height:60px;
width:600px;
float:left;
position:relative;
margin:0 0 0 0;
background-color:#31353E;
box-shadow:inset 7px 0 7px -7px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 7px 0 7px -7px #000;
-moz-box-shadow:inset 7px 0 7px -7px #000;
-ms-box-shadow:inset 7px 0 7px -7px #000;
-o-box-shadow:inset 7px 0 7px -7px #000;
}
#profiledata{
height:559px;
width:600px;
float:left;
margin:1px 0 0 0;
background-color:#31353E;
box-shadow:inset 7px 0 7px -7px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 7px 0 7px -7px #000;
-moz-box-shadow:inset 7px 0 7px -7px #000;
-ms-box-shadow:inset 7px 0 7px -7px #000;
-o-box-shadow:inset 7px 0 7px -7px #000;
}
#d1{
height:100%;
width:600px;
float:left;
position:relative;
margin: 0 0 0 1175px;
background-color:#31353E;
box-shadow:inset 7px 0 7px -7px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 7px 0 7px -7px #000;
-moz-box-shadow:inset 7px 0 7px -7px #000;
-ms-box-shadow:inset 7px 0 7px -7px #000;
-o-box-shadow:inset 7px 0 7px -7px #000;
display:none;
}
#d2, #d3, #d4, #d5 {
height:100%;
width:600px;
float:left;
position:relative;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
background-color:#31353E;
box-shadow:inset 7px 0 7px -7px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 7px 0 7px -7px #000;
-moz-box-shadow:inset 7px 0 7px -7px #000;
-ms-box-shadow:inset 7px 0 7px -7px #000;
-o-box-shadow:inset 7px 0 7px -7px #000;
display:none;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML code?

Comment: can you also show the html?

Comment: @BeNdErR i had added the html and css of the page

Comment: @Sarcastic, i had added the html and css of the page

Comment: why are you using jquery to do this and not css media queries?

Comment: @Chausser i don't have an idea how to do that...

Comment: Can you put an alert just before calling profdisplayer function, like alert(cwidth);
profdisplayer();
and see whether it returns the original width or after resize?

Comment: hmmm... function profdisplayer is not working properly...
it is only working on window load... because i had declared it outside .resize() also... and on setting default showing cwidth 5349..

Comment: vishal vasistha I added an answer showing you how to use css media queries to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no need to do any css media query thing..
i did it with jquery

```
$(window).on('resize', function(event){
    var awidth = $(window).width();
    if (awidth>bwidth)
        {   profdisplayer();
            bwidth = awidth;
        }
    if (bwidth>awidth)
    {
        profhider();
        var getdivname = $('#dcontainer').find("div").first();
        var divid = getdivname.attr("id");
        var divno = divid.match(/[0-9]+/);
        $('#d'+divno).show();
        bwidth=awidth;
        }
    });
```

profdisplayer will display on resize if width is increasing

```
   function profdisplayer()
{
    var cwidth = $(window).width();
    var i=1390;
    for(var j=1; j<=8;j++){
    if (cwidth>i){   
        $("#d"+j).show();
        i=i+600;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

profhider will hide on resize if width is decreases

```
   function profhider()
{
    var dwidth = $(window).width();
    var z = 5375;
        for(var k=8; k>=1;k--) {
            if(dwidth<z)
            {
            $("#d"+k).hide();
            z=z-600;
            $('#dcontainer').first().show();
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using only css, with the media queries.

HTML :

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="containerchild">
<div id="hidden"></div>
        <div id="myfavcontainer">
            <div id="myfav"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="profilecontainer">
                <div id="abouttab"></div>
                <div id="horirule620"></div>
                <div id="profiledata"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="d1" class="hide"></div>
        <div id="d2" class="hide"></div>
        <div id="d3" class="hide"></div>
        <div id="d4" class="hide"></div>
        <div id="d5" class="hide"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
   .hide { display: none }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Media queries are designed to do exactly what you are looking for. From my understanding its looking like you want to show the "d#" divs every 600 pixels with the first one being shown if the window is bigger than 1390px.

So to accomplish this we will need a few media queries the first one will show the d1 box

```
@media (min-width:1390px){
    #d1{
        display: block;
    }
}
```

This will check and make sure that window width is a minimum of 1390, if it is then the css wrapped in it will be executed.

So for all of it should look like:

```
#d1,#d2,#d3,#d4,#d5{
    display: none;
}
@media (min-width:1390px){
    #d1{
        display: block;
    }
}
@media (min-width:1990px){
    #d2{
        display: block;
    }
}
@media (min-width:2590px){
    #d3{
        display: block;
    }
}
@media (min-width:3190px){
    #d4{
        display: block;
    }
}
@media (min-width:3790px){
    #d5{
        display: block;
    }
}
```

This will show all of them as the page gets bigger then re-hide them as it contracts.

Comment: well, if i will that in this way i won't be able to slide the div(s)... anyway.... thanx for the help... maybe it can be useful for any other purpose... thanx alot...